# Mapping third party domain to aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Problem**: I'm trying to map godaddy's domain to aws elastic beanstalk url. I read their documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) down to the last letter, followed their instructions, and I still can't get it to work. Whenever I go to mydomain.com, I keep getting **Bad Request(400)** every single time but the actual amazon elastic beanstalk url works fine.

I found few other posts on stackoverflow related to this problem, followed the instructions in those posts, basically I searched everywhere I could. Even called up godaddy's customer service, spent couple hours with them, they said the problem is probably at amazon's end and that the domain is getting resolved but the request gets denied when it reaches amazon.

I even tried Router 53 method, it's not working at all. I'm basically at a dead end.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a look at this: http://compositecode.com/2014/01/23/mapping-domain-names-w-name-com-and-amazon-route-53/

Comment: What changes are you doing on the godaddy website? If you are creating your route53 domain name like '<your-domain-name>.com' which has a CNAME record pointing to 'your-environment-cname>.elasticbeanstalk.com' then you need to provide the nameservers listed by route53 on your godaddy configuration page.

Comment: Hey Rohit, thanks for response. I've setup route53 exactly as written in that article, also I've already listed the nameservers  of route53 in godaddy's settings, 'www' cname is pointing to beanstalk app url as well. It's still showing 'Bad Request(400)'.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `dig <your-go-daddy-domain>` and `dig <your-elasticbeanstalk-domain>`?

Comment: Also the change propagation at GoDaddy can take several hours to propagate. I assume you have waited long enough.

Comment: Yeah, I've waited for a day. I'm assuming even though the updates aren't propagated everywhere, at least I should be able to see the website from my location.

Comment: For dig mydomain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> mydomain.com

;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 539
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.  60 IN A 54.213.185.214

;; Query time: 132 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 02 22:26:52 MDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59

Comment: For dig my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33777
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com. 60 IN A 54.213.185.214

;; Query time: 52 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 02 22:28:16 MDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 91

Comment: So it seems both are resolving to 54.213.185.214. I would guess `dig <your-elb>` would return the same thing if you try a couple of times. The answer may be different every time for your elb.

Comment: Actually, I noticed, dig mydomain.com gives a different ip address sometimes. It shows 184.168.221.33 instead of 54.213.185.214 and 184.168.221.33 is the @-A record in godaddy's settings. Does that A record have anything to do with the error? I noticed when I entered route53 nameservers, godaddy automatically created that A record, so I left it as it is.

Comment: I don't know why that A record was created. You can try deleting it and create it back again if things don't work. If I open 54.213.185.214 in my browser I see a Bad Request. Is this the IP of your ELB?

Comment: Yes, that's the ip of the elb.

Comment: That was another strange thing I noticed, that I could access through elb url just fine, but when I open it's ip address in the browser it wouldn't work.

Comment: any ideas why it's not working? :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finally fix it. Here's a follow up post - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=157914&tstart=0

After I deployed the code, I had just forgotten to change the allowed host settings again in the code itself, so after I added the mydomain.com to allowed hosts it finally worked.

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS` gets me everytime! Bad Request(400)? Check ALLOWED_HOSTS. Thanks for a hint in the right direction.